# making regex more specific to exclude certain characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
import re
s = '01.11.11 12/12/1981 1*51*12 . 22|1|13 03-02-1919 1-22-12 or 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 01.11.18 or 2.2.17 or 02.02.18 or 12.1.16 12.23.1943 01-23-11 not 12.23.192 not 02.02.1'
```

I have the following string `s` and I want to extract all the dates that are separated by 3 items: either 1) a period e.g. `01.11.11` or 2) a dash e.g. `1-22-12` or 3)a backslash e.g. `12/12/1981`.

To do so, I have tried the following

```
reg = r'\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.(?:\d{4}|\d{2})' 
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
```

It works but gives me some unwanted things such as `'1*51*12'` and `22|1|13'`

```
['01.11.11',
 '12/12/1981',
 '1*51*12',
 '22|1|13',
 '03-02-1919',
 '1-22-12',
 '01-23-18',
 '03-23-1984',
 '01.11.18',
 '2.2.17',
 '02.02.18',
 '12.1.16',
 '12.23.1943',
 '01-23-11',
 '12.23.19']
```

I want my output to be

```
['01.11.11',
 '12/12/1981',
 '03-02-1919',
 '1-22-12',
 '01-23-18',
 '03-23-1984',
 '01.11.18',
 '2.2.17',
 '02.02.18',
 '12.1.16',
 '12.23.1943',
 '01-23-11',
 '12.23.19']
```

How do I tweak `reg` to be more specific and get my desired output?

Comment: is the day between the month and the year or the first one? so far what you will get will be 99/99/99 if at all you do not specify the maximum within your regex and just use `\d` you need to be more specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b((?:\d{1,2}(?:\.|\/|-)){2}(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\b`

This regex will match all of your test cases, and will filter improper years, such as `12.23.192`

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/NtL6rv/1/)

Comment: this will take `23\23\201` which date is that?

Comment: OP didn't specify if they wanted `MM-DD-YYYY` or `DD-MM-YYYY` - also, did you test `23\23\201`? It isn't matched.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of matching `.` inbetween the sets of numbers - which will match any character - only match the ones you are looking for; `. - /`.

Fixed regex:

```
\d{1,2}[\.\/-]\d{1,2}[\.\/-](?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b
```

Also adds a word boundary at the end to avoid matching dates with only 3 digit years.

regex101 example: https://regex101.com/r/0r6jru/2

Comment: Thank you, I forgot to test against his original string! Fixed.

Comment: Also fails against those with three leading digits, but OP didn't mention that; downvote removed. Don't forget to update your regex101 link!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to match the same delimiter for the whole "date like" pattern, you could make use of a capturing group and a backreference `\1` so that a date like `12/12.1981` is not matched.

Note that the pattern does not validate a date itself.

```
\b\d{1,2}([./-])\d{1,2}\1(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `\d{1,2}` Match 1-2 digits
- `([./-])` Capture group 1, match `.` `/` or `-`
- `\d{1,2}\1` Match 1-2 digits and a backreference to the first captured delimiter
- `(?:\d{4}|\d{2})` Match eithe 4 or 2 digits
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XMn4XS/1) | [Python demo](http://ideone.com/GzodZ4)

For example using [re.finditer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.finditer) (as re.findall will return the capturing group which is the delimiter)

```
import re
reg = r"\b\d{1,2}([./-])\d{1,2}\1(?:\d{4}|\d{2})\b"
s = "01.11.11 12/12/1981 1*51*12 . 22|1|13 03-02-1919 1-22-12 or 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 01.11.18 or 2.2.17 or 02.02.18 or 12.1.16 12.23.1943 01-23-11 not 12.23.192 not 02.02.1"

matches = re.finditer(reg, s)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    print(match.group())
```

Comment: back referencing within findall?? that means there is a captured group and hence this wont work