# modification of making regex more specific to exclude certain characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string, text

```
import re
s = '01.20/15 01/20.1915 1/1/19 01.11.11 1.8-24 3-4.12 01/20-09 12/12/1981 12-01/2001 1*51*12  22|1|13 03-02-1919 1-22-12 or 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 01.11.18 or 2.2.17 or 02.02.18 or 12.1.16 12.23.1943 01-23-11 not 12.23.192 not 02.02.1'
```

I have the following string `s` which is a modification from [making regex more specific to exclude certain characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240212/making-regex-more-specific-to-exclude-certain-characters)

I want to get all dates so I use

```
reg = r'\b((?:\d{1,2}(?:\.|\/|-)){2}(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\b'
r1 = re.findall(reg,s)
r1
```

and I get

```
['01.20/15',
 '01/20.1915',
 '1/1/19',
 '01.11.11',
 '1.8-24',
 '3-4.12',
 '01/20-09',
 '12/12/1981',
 '12-01/2001',
 '03-02-1919',
 '1-22-12',
 '01-23-18',
 '03-23-1984',
 '01.11.18',
 '2.2.17',
 '02.02.18',
 '12.1.16',
 '12.23.1943',
 '01-23-11']
```

This is close to what I want but I do not want strings that have a mix of `.` or `/` or `-` e.g. `'01.20/15'` or `'3-4.12'` or `3-4.12` etc

My desired output is this

```
['1/1/19',
 '01.11.11',
 '12/12/1981',
 '03-02-1919',
 '1-22-12',
 '01-23-18',
 '03-23-1984',
 '01.11.18',
 '2.2.17',
 '02.02.18',
 '12.1.16',
 '12.23.1943',
 '01-23-11']
```

which does not contain any numbers that have a mix of `.` or `/` or `-` e.g. `'01.20/15'` or `'3-4.12'`

I have also tried modifying `reg`

```
reg = r'\b((?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\b|\\b/|-\b)){2}(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))\b'
```

but this doesnt quite work

How do I further modify `reg` to get my desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that maybe a back-reference would not be such a bad idea here:

```
\b([0-9]{1,2}([./-])[0-9]{1,2}\2[0-9]{2,4})\b
```

or

```
\b[0-9]{1,2}([.\/-])[0-9]{1,2}\1(?:[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{4})\b
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iEWjIT/1/)

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r'\b([0-9]{1,2}([./-])[0-9]{1,2}\2\d{2,4})\b'
string = '''
01.20/15 01/20.1915  01.11.11 1.8-24 3-4.12 01/20-09 12/12/1981 12-01/2001 1*51*12  22|1|13 03-02-1919 1-22-12 or 01-23-18 or 03-23-1984 01.11.18 or 2.2.17 or 02.02.18 or 12.1.16 12.23.1943 01-23-11 not 12.23.192 not 02.02.1

'''

matches = re.findall(regex, string)

output = []
for match in matches:
    output.append(match[0])

print(output)
```

#### Output

> ['01.11.11', '12/12/1981', '03-02-1919', '1-22-12', '01-23-18',
>   '03-23-1984', '01.11.18', '2.2.17', '02.02.18', '12.1.16',
>   '12.23.1943', '01-23-11', '12.23.192']

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dfwb7J/1/)

Comment: thank you for the code. this is close to what I want except I am looking for the `['01.11.11''` format instead of `'[(01.11.11', '.')`

Comment: Thanks! And actually this code is close but it's capturing `12.23.192'` which it should not

Comment: and good point. I don't want values like `45-90-4000`. I only want dates. But I will ask another question to handle this as well

Answer (score 2):

Can use findall() with a single capture group instead of using a backref is something like

`\b((?:\d{1,2}\.\d{1,2}\.|\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/|\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-)(?:\d{2}|\d{4}))\b`

https://regex101.com/r/V2AXPj/1

Expanded

```
 \b 
 (                             # (1 start)
      (?:
           \d{1,2} \. \d{1,2} \. 
        |  
           \d{1,2} / \d{1,2} /
        |  
           \d{1,2} - \d{1,2} -
      )
      (?: \d{2} | \d{4} )
 )                             # (1 end)
 \b
```

Answer (score 0):

This may get you closer to what you are looking for:

```
RE = r'((?:\d{1,2}(?:\.|\/|-)){2}\d{1,4})'
```

This will match on most of the input provided, with the exception of the following strings:

```
11-11-12-13-15.1645
01-01-11-12
```

This regex will capture both `11-11-12` and `13-15.1645` for the first example, and `01-01-11` for the second. You could do some pre-processing on your longer strings to split on the `-`|`/`|`.` delimiters. By splitting on the first delimiter, then second, ... until you find a match by using `re.match(post_split[0])` and `re.match(post_split[1])`.